# What is a "connection" in algebraic terms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, connections

It seems that I read this somewhere else, but I did not find the correct reference now.

We know that a vector bundle $E\to M$ is a (projective or locally free) module of $C^\infty(M)$. Then how to express the connection on $E$ pure algebraicaly?

In other words, the formulation should lead to a notion of connection for any module over a (differential?) algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X \to S$ is morphism of locally ringed spaces and $M$ is some $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, a connection of $M$ over $S$ is an $\mathcal{O}_S$-homomorphism $\nabla: M \to M \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \Omega^1_{X/S}$ such that $\nabla(am)=a \nabla(m) + m \otimes d(a)$ for local sections $a$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $m$ of $M$. This works for schemes, but also for manifolds (both are locally ringed spaces). In the case of manifolds, we can use partitions of unity etc. and deduce that $\nabla$ is completely determined by its map on global sections (this is the connection to Vladimir's answer).

Comment: In the smooth case (where this works perfectly, but also in the general one), one can also consider the transposed map $Der(X/S)\otimes M\to M$, which connects nicely with module structures of the sheaf of differential operators (which is, in the smooth case in char. zero, generated by derivations and functions). Since one can define diff. ops. on general rings (even non-commutative) à la Grothendieck, this gives an extension.

Answer (score 3):

First, technically, $E$ is not a $C^\infty(M)$-module, but $\Gamma(E)$, the space of sections of $E$, is.

One can define a connection as a $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $\nabla\colon \Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)\otimes_{C^\infty(M)}\Lambda^1(M)$ such that, for any $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $\gamma\in\Gamma(E)$, one has
$$
 \nabla(f\gamma)=f\nabla(\gamma)+\gamma\otimes df.
$$
Here $\Lambda^1(M)$ is the $C^\infty(M)$-module of differential $1$-forms on $M$.

(For example, see R. Wells "Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds" Chap. III Sec. 1.)

Comment: what is $\Lambda^1(M)$ for a usual algebra?

Comment: Sorry I do not quite understand the question. What do you mean by a usual algebra?

Comment: @Vladimir: Ma wants to understand how to define a connection in a purely algebraic sense, e.g. can one give a definition of a connection on an $A$-module $M$ for an arbitrary algebra $A$ which reduces to the ordinary definition when $A = C^{\infty}(X)$ for a smooth manifold $X$ and $M$ is the module of sections of a vector bundle?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get around the use of $\Omega^1_M$ as an external input, because there are too many algebraic Kähler differentials.